# i want to move one table row to another and delete that row from old table

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

```
insert into dbo.OffEmployeeRecord 
select * from dbo.EmployeeRecord where Code=1
```

this code copies data from `table_1` to `table_2` but i want to move it( deletion after copy from first table) in single query

Answer (score 0):

You can write stored procedures to perform such action

```
createProc [dbo].[ProcRemoveEmoRecord]
(
@CodId varchar(50)
)
As 
begin

insert into dbo.OffEmployeeRecord 
select * from dbo.EmployeeRecord where Code=@CodId

delete from dbo.EmployeeRecord where Code=@CodId

end
```

after creating the above sp, you can perform the required action by executing the above procedure

Comment: I think you need to implement transactions in this procedure